# reading and mapping two lists into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, mapping, grouping

**WHAT I HAVE**

```
list_1 = ["5","1","6","1","2","5"]
list_2 = ["1","3","9","15","16","16"]
```

*Please note the duplicates in the lists*

**WHAT I WANT**

I am trying to create a dictionary where the uniques values from list 1 are the keys, and the average of the corresponding elements in list 2 are the values.

In other words, the dictionary I am after is the following:

```
{"1": 9.0, "2": 16, "5": 8.5, "6": 9.0}
```

I am not looking specifically for someone to just give me the answer (although that would be appreciated). Therefore, if someone could just point me in the right direction or give me some topics to look into that would be great.

Comment: `zip` two lists, use `itertools.groupby` to group them by the elements in `list_1`, then calculate averages in a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a manual way to do it with loops, this should explain the logic flow.

```
# Two lists
list_1 = ["5","1","6","1","2","5"]
list_2 = ["1","3","9","15","16","16"]

# Empty dictionary
results ={}

# Go through list on, create a key in the dict if the key does not exist
# Then add the value to the array identified by that key
# Cast to int to make life easier
for i in range(0, len(list_1)):
    if (not list_1[i] in results):
        results[list_1[i]] = []
    results[list_1[i]].append(int(list_2[i]))

# Print the results before you average it
print(results)
# >> {'5': [1, 16], '1': [3, 15], '6': [9], '2': [16]}

# Iterate through all keys and average the values, assigning the result to that key
for k in results:
    results[k] = (sum(results[k])/len(results[k]))

print(results)
# >> {'5': 8.5, '1': 9.0, '6': 9.0, '2': 16.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do

1. Take out the unique elements from `list_1`. Hint: Use `set()` function.
2. Loop through the unique item list found in step 1.
3. For each index found sum the corresponding values from `list_2` and perform average.
4. Store the value of unique item in a dictionary along with the average in Step 3.

Hope this will help you!